# Python joining tuples from a while loop into a list

Tags: python, list, tuples, typeerror

I'm iterating over a large list of tuples of the form

```
num_list = [('A15', 2, 'BC', 721.16), ('A21', 3, 'AB', 631.31), ('A42', 4, 'EE', 245.43)]
```

I'm trying to find the maximum fourth element of each tuple over a rolling 5 value period for the second element for each different value of the first element, all the different first element values are stored in a set called account_2 and output that in a form

```
ID   Max
A21  400
A15  489
```

My code is below:

```
first_value = 1
fifth_value = 5
maximum = []    

while first_value <= 24 and fifth_value <= 28:
    for num_list[0][0] in account_2:
        result = max([i for i in num_list if i[1] <= fifth_value and i[1] >= first_value], key = lambda  x:x[3])
        maximum.extend(result)
        first_value += 1
        fifth_value += 1
```

I think I need to substitute the 1st `0` in `num_list[0][0]` for a variable to loop over so it loops over every single tuple in the list but in my testing of just the first tuple i.e. in the current case I'm getting the error `TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: `num_list[0][0] += (your_new_val,)`

Comment: Each tuple contains exactly one "fourth element", so what do you mean by the maximum fourth element?  And how does a rolling 5 value period for the second element have a fourth element?

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the line

```
for num_list[0][0] in account_2:
```

which tries to assign values from `account_2` to `numlist[0][0]` while `numlist[0]` is a tuple, that is an immutable object.

The minimum fix would be:

```
while first_value <= 24 and fifth_value <= 28:
    for acc in account_2:
        try:
            result = max([i for i in num_list if i[1] <= fifth_value and i[1] >= first_value and i[0] == acc ], key = lambda  x:x[3])
        except ValueError:
            result = ()
        maximum.extend(result)
        first_value += 1
        fifth_value += 1
```

The `try: ... except...` is necessary because `max` raises a ValueError when it is passed an empty sequence.